# how to start activity after call some requests by retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to start new activity after call and finish 7 difference requests in parallel using retrofit.
Where should I call startActivity() method?
here is my wrong trying.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    api.method1(args..).enqueue(new Callback<Response1>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call<Response1> call, Response<Response1> response) {
                                            //do some things
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Call<Response1> call, Throwable t) {
                                            t.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    });

                                     ..
                                     ..
                                     ..
                                  api.method7(args..).enqueue(new Callback<Response7>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call<Response7> call, Response<Response7> response) {
                                            //do some things
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Call<Response7> call, Throwable t) {
                                            t.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    });
                                 startActivity(new Intent(current.this,next.class));
                            }).start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Rxjava with Retrofit and then you can do something like (assuming method1,method2 etc return `Observable<Response1>`, `Observable<Response2>` etc)

`Observable.zip(api.method1, api.method2, ...)`

Comment: thnks for your answer, I dont know anything about rxjava, I will try to study it now.

Comment: I would also encourage you to look in to using `Retrolambda` when using `RxJava` (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrolambda/article.html) ....or Jack compiler when it's more mature (https://source.android.com/source/jack.html)

Comment: hmm, it works for me where when I click on it...pasting it here again in case there was some formatting issue - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrolambda/article.html

Comment: Here you can see a zip example to understand a little better https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/combining/ObservableZip.java And here in general some practicle examples https://github.com/politrons/reactive